# In jquery parent of same sibling when compared returning false

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, tree

I am having a tree of ul li. I have either a checkbox or a radio control for each set of child nodes.

What I am doing is when I check any checkbox or radio I want all the nodes to be unchecked except for the sibling (in case of checkbox). So I have written my jquery here.

My jquery is working expect for one problem which I need help.

It is below:

```
if($(this).parent().parent().parent() != $(elem).parent().parent().parent())
```

The whole fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/LSw4d/3/)
In the above condition when I compare the same parents I should get `false` sometimes.
Please look into the code and help to understand why they are always returning true.

Comment: have you tried comparing the DOM elements instead? `if($(this).parent().parent().parent()[0] != $(elem).parent().parent().parent()[0])`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make sense to compare jQuery objects, because each call to `$()` returns a new object.

Comment: Also instead of that fragile `.parent()` chain, you might consider using something like `.closest('li')` to find the first parent `<li>` node.

Comment: @jbabey I did not see your comment, I just post the answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: @EnesUnal you put in the effort to answer, not me :)

Comment: You guys are all smart, I am using closest() and get(0). Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#tree").find("input").bind("change", function(){
        setStateForAllInputControls($("#tree"), this);
    });
});

function setStateForAllInputControls(o, elem) {
    //alert($(elem).attr("name"));

    if($(elem).attr("checked") == "checked") {
        $(o).find("input").each(function(){

            //problem is in this if condition
            if($(this).parent().parent().parent().get(0) != $(elem).parent().parent().parent().get(0)) {
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            }
        });
        $(elem).attr("checked", "checked");
    }
}
```

will do the trick